# In what cases people know that I see their stories on instagram or mystalk?

Tags: account-security, access-control, internet, instagram

I don't have an instagram account, but I always look to my friends' profiles on instagram or mystalk and see their stories.

BTW my google account is always signed in when I check their stories on instagram or mystalk. So my question is: **in what cases they will know that I see their stories?** For example, can they know (from my google account) that it is me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In what cases they will know that I see their stories? For example, can they know (from my google account) that it is me?

Assuming with 'they', you mean your friends, it is highly unlikely they will know it was you unless they would know your IP address and use some sort of analytics to see who visited and from where.

It used to be possible for websites to determine whether a user is logged in to their Google account or not. I do not know if this still is the case, but this was the only information that was possible to gather from Google.